# Image won't center, only align left or right

Tags: html, css

I can't get my image to center under my < h1>. If I try float:left, then it aligns to the furthest left. If I try right, it does so correctly. But center just stays on the left.

CSS

```
    .b {
            color: blue;}
    .r {
            color: red;}
    .key { 
            border-style: groove;
            width:75px;}
    .centre {
            text-align:center;}









 <h1 class="main"><ul>Amsterdam Itinerary</ul></h1>

 img src="*img*" alt="dam" width="140" height="100" style="float:center"/>

  <div class="key centre">Key:<br><br>
  <span class="b">Matt <br> </span>
  <span class="r">Kerry <br> </span>
   Both <br>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you want centered? Look this example http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-align

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to actually align under your H1 then you will need to also center your H1 and wrap it in a container div.

```
<style>
    .b {color: blue;}
    .r {color: red;}
    .key { 
        border-style: groove;
        width:75px;
    }
    img.centre {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .centre {text-align:center;}
    .container{width:350px;}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="main centre">Amsterdam Itinerary</h1>
    <img class="centre" src="img-source" alt="dam" width="140" height="100" />

    <div class="key centre">Key:<br><br>
        <span class="b">Matt <br> </span>
        <span class="r">Kerry <br> </span>
        Both <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you just want to center the image then you can just use the img.centre style.

```
img.centre {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/gzvehb9y/

Answer (score 0):

remove float style of Image.
use margin:0 auto; instead;

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float of the img and also wrap it in a div and give that div the following css:

```
text-align: center;
```